# How to return entity having a List of another entity as a property from function?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

How to write a SQL function which would return a class (entity) which has a property which is a List of another class entity using the Entity Framework ?

I have gone through [TVF in EF](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/table-valued-function-in-entity-framework5.aspx) and this is the closest to what I am trying to achieve except that I have a view model wherein there is a `List<entity2>`.

How do I write a robust function that would return the kind of resultset which will be favourable to the view model?

Some code

```
    public class Entity1
    {
        public List <Entity2> extra { get; set; }
        public string img { get; set; }
    } 

   public class Entity2
   {
       public string itemType { get; set; }
       public int Quantity { get; set; }

   }
```

I want to create a view with the view model `Entity1`. How can I do this?

Comment: You want to return it from SQL filled with data ? OR you want to pass it to view  ?Or you want to pass it from view to controller?

Comment: I want to pass the data from sql into a view. And i have already written `Entity1` to pass data from view to controller. So i guess it will be favorable if i use the same to pass from controller to view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your view model to view like this.First create an object of view model and fill it with data.

```
DBContext db=new DBContext();
Entity ent=new Entity();
ent.extra=db.Entity2.ToList();//This will get all data from db for entity2 table
ent.img="some value";
return return View(ent);
```

And in view you will do like this. So you will have data in it

```
@model Entity
```

Replace name of DbContext if required.

Comment: It's not a good practice to use the EF entity as the model for view.